# Get localStorage in NextJs getInitialProps

Tags: authentication, local-storage, next.js

I working with localStorage token in my next.js application. I tried to get the localStorage on page getInitialProps but, it returns `undefined`.

Here is an example,

```
Dashboard.getInitialProps = async () => {
  const token = localStorage.getItem('auth');
  const res = await fetch(`${process.env.API_URL}/pages/about`, {
    headers: { 'Authorization': token }
  });
  const data = await res.json();

  return { page: data };
}
```

Comment: `getInitialProps` runs entirely in server side, and `LocalStorage` exists solely on client-side, so you don't have any way to access it. Use another means of sending the data, like cookies, http body or the like.

Comment: Unlike the new `getServerSideProps` which always run on server-side, `getInitialProps` actually can run on client-side during client transitions. But I agree that cookies is a better solution in this scenario.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> For the initial page load, `getInitialProps` will run on the server
>   only. `getInitialProps` will then run on the client when navigating to a
>   different route via the `next/link` component or by using `next/router`. [Docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/getInitialProps)

This means you will not be able to access `localStorage`(client-side-only) all the time and will have to handle it:

```
Dashboard.getInitialProps = async ({ req }) => {
  let token;
  if (req) {
    // server
    return { page: {} };
  } else {
    // client
    const token = localStorage.getItem("auth");
    const res = await fetch(`${process.env.API_URL}/pages/about`, {
      headers: { Authorization: token },
    });
    const data = await res.json();
    return { page: data };
  }
};
```

If you want to get the user's token for the initial page load, you have to store the token in `cookies` instead of `localStorage` which @alejandro also mentioned in the comment.

Comment: I have tried your solution it's working fine when I change routes. Yes, it's not working for the initial page loading. But, I have already solved the issue using the cookie as per @alejandro instruction. I believe a cookie is the best solution. Thanks for your help.